# Thread index as an memory location index in CUDA

Tags: memory, cuda, gpu, matrix-multiplication

By definition, a thread is a path of execution within a process. 
But during the implementation of a kernel, a thread_id or global_index is generated to access a memory location allocated. For instance, in the Matrix Multiplication code below, `ROW` and `COL` are generated to access matrix A and B sequential. 
My doubt here is, index generated isn't pointing to a thread(by definition), instead, it is used to access the location of the data in the memory, then why do we refer to it as thread index or global thread index and why not memory index or something else?

```
__global__ void matrixMultiplicationKernel(float* A, float* B, float* C, int N) {

    int ROW = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
    int COL = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;

    float tmpSum = 0;

    if (ROW < N && COL < N) {
        // each thread computes one element of the block sub-matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            tmpSum += A[ROW * N + i] * B[i * N + COL];
        }
    }
    C[ROW * N + COL] = tmpSum;
}
```

Comment: "By definition, a thread is a path of execution within a process" -- that is a pretty strange definition.

Comment: This is the source of definition I've used.https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/thread-in-operating-system/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question seems to be mostly about semantics, so let's start at [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing))

> .... a thread of execution is the smallest sequence of programmed
> instructions that can be managed independently by a scheduler ....

That is pretty much describes exactly what s thread in CUDA is -- the kernel is the sequence of instructions, and the scheduler is the warp/thread scheduler in each streaming multiprocessor on the GPU.

The code in your question is calculating the unique ID of the thread in the kernel launch, as it is abstracted in the CUDA programming/execution model. It has no intrinsic relationship to memory layouts, only to the unique ID in the kernel launch. The fact it is being used to ensure that each parallel operation is being performed on a different memory location is programming technique and nothing more.

Thread ID seems like a logical moniker to me, but to paraphrase Miles Davis when he was asked what the name of the jam his band just played at the Isle of Wight festival in 1970: "call it whatever you want".